# ArrayList delay in return

Tags: java, arraylist

In my application i have an ArrayList that is returned from another class, and in the next line i need to get the size of it to create an another array where i'm going to put some addresses, and it always return the size 0, in the debug mode i could see that more forward in the program the size of the ArrayList is correct, but there all that i wanted to do is already wrong, I have tried to use Thread.sleep(10000) and a 10000 blank loop, and still nothing, please someone help, and sorry for my english, here it is a little bit of the code:

```
    caixas = campo.getCaixas(); //this is where i return the ArrayList
    enderecosM = new byte[caixas.size()][2];
    for (int j = 0; j < caixas.size(); j++) {
        enderecosM[j][0]=0;
        enderecosM[j][1]=0;
    }
```

There are 2 ArrayLists with the same problem, i have they filled in the paint component from a JPanel called PanelDesenho, i call the repaint method before calling the array lists.

```
private void desenha() {
    nLinhas = (int) Integer.valueOf(textLinhas.getText());
    nColunas = (int) Integer.valueOf(textColunas.getText());
    total = nLinhas * nColunas;
       //pass the parameters to create the ArrayLists.
    campo.defParametros(nLinhas, nColunas, matrizList);
    panelDesenho.repaint();
    panelDesenho.revalidate();
    sensores = campo.getSensores();
    caixas = campo.getCaixas();
    caixasLado = campo.getCaixasLado();
    enderecosM = new byte[caixas.size()][2];
    for (int j = 0; j < caixas.size(); j++) {
        enderecosM[j][0]=0;
        enderecosM[j][1]=0;
    }
    enderecosL = new byte[caixasLado.size()][2];
    for (int j = 0; j < caixas.size(); j++) {
        enderecosL[j][0]=0;
        enderecosL[j][1]=0;
    }
}
```

Now is there the PaintComponent method:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            campo.desMatriz(g2d);
        }
```

And the code from the method where i fill the ArrayLists:

```
public void defParametros(int lin, int col, ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
    linhas = lin;
    colunas = col;
    arrList = arr;
}



public void desMatriz(Graphics2D g2d) {
    int i, n, k = 0, z=0, y=0;
    sensores.clear();
    caixas.clear();
    caixasLado.clear();
    for (n = 0; n < linhas; n++) {
        for (i = 0; i < colunas; i++) {
            if (i%2==0 && i<colunas-1){
                caixas.add(new Rectangle2D.Double(145+50*i, 10+100*n, 30, 20));
                g2d.fill(caixas.get(z));
                z++;
            }
            if (n%2==0 && n<linhas-1){
                if (i==0){
                    caixasLado.add(new Rectangle2D.Double(30, 155+100*n, 20, 30));
                    g2d.fill(caixasLado.get(y));
                    y++;
                }
                if (i==colunas-1){
                    caixasLado.add(new Rectangle2D.Double(170+50*i, 155+100*n, 20, 30));
                    g2d.fill(caixasLado.get(y));
                    y++;
                }
            }
            sensores.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(100 + 50 * i, 60 + 100 * n, 20, 20));
            g2d.fill(sensores.get(k));
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

and finally, where i return the ArrayLists:

```
public ArrayList<Rectangle2D> getCaixas(){
    return caixas;
}

public ArrayList<Rectangle2D> getCaixasLado(){
    return caixasLado;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of getCaixas() function or where you are creating campo object coz that will decide what would be the size and why you are getting size as 0.

Answer (score 1):

> i could see that more forward in the program the size of the ArrayList
>   is correct, but there all that i wanted to do is already wrong.

It seems you are working on a shared list, which gets modified by some statement either in your current class or some other class. And hence you see that list is not filled at the time when you execute:

```
caixas = campo.getCaixas(); //this is where i return the ArrayList
```

but it is populated later due to execution of some other piece of code.

You need to find the code where the list is getting populated and if you want you can execute that prior to the statement mentioned above.

Comment: Thats the weird part, i call the populated code before I return the array list, I'm going to edit my answer so I can show more the problem.

Comment: If you're doing it between two threads, you need to synchronize() on something. Different threads may have outdated processor cache for user-perceivable periods of time, otherwise..  If not multi-threaded, it's just an order-of-execution (common or garden variety) error in your code. Have you tried breakpoints to see when it's called, vs when it's inited?

Comment: Tere is no thread, i tried the thread to make time, i thought that if making more time for the program it could return right, because i don't do nothing and in the next click of the mouse the ArrayLists are right, but the addresses arrays are already with the wrong size

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to solve the problem itself but i have find a way to make program work, the way that i describe in the question it just did not work and i have no idea why, i just had to call the functions getCaixas and getCaixasLado in other part of the program that it has to be done forward in the program, it was the only way to make it work, if someone know what is the problem there please share with us, this is a really annoying problem.